# Colloquial English listening comprehension

Tags: colloquial-language, comprehension, listening

I'm trying to improve my listening comprehension especially with those colloquial/slang style every day English, please lend me a ear on these tricky parts.

1. And so, it's a CustomerModel and we'll look at that ??? minute. Just like the PhysicalProductModel ??? [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=153)
2. ??? six properties [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=249)
3. I'll pull (it?) over here. It says Simulating shipping the Nerf football to Tim, (he's???) in Scranton [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=265)
4. and we (gonna??) have a same
   type of thing, we (gonna??) have a title  ??? a title for now.  OK, so (got a?) title [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=319)
5. and that might work, except for if we have things that aren't even or ??? even less equal [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=435)
6. So, an interface, let's talk about that ??? and then we'll actually see it in action [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=474)
7. Now, a naming convention ??? the naming convention [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=512)
8. first thing (you/we/???) do [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=554)
9. So ??? physical product model. [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=568)
10. otherwise, there's no point ??? in the contract if no one can see it. [position](https://youtu.be/A7qwuFnyIpM?t=623)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a transcription service

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica I'm so sorry about this, but this is not a transcription at all. Transcription is to write out those main words to help understanding the main meaning of a material, what I'm trying to get help here is those not-so-crucial words that hard to understand for ESL students. Beside that, I have done my best to write out all the other part of it, leaving only those small part for those who would like to help. I can't think of a better way to learn colloquial language than this.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the Subtitles icon? They're not perfect, but better  than nothing..

Comment: @ Kate Bunting Not only I've opened the subtitle in YouTube, but I also used two other online transcription services to give me more options. With transcriptions generated from all three different algorithms and the help by <0.5x playing speed, I've dedicated a whole day to learning the first 10 minutes of the video. I still can't even hear the pronunciation clearly even with the answer below, like in 7 and 9. It's like a magic for me.

Comment: @preachers In 7, he pronounces "probably" as "prolly", which is a very common pronunciation in the US (sometimes you even see it spelt "prolly" in informal usage), although his /l/ is unclear, so it sounds more like "pro'y". (In British English the more common contracted form of "probably" is "prob'ly".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. And so, it's a CustomerModel and we'll look at that in a minute. Just like the PhysicalProductModel (which) we'll look at in a minute.
2. It's just (let's see, like) six properties
3. I'll pull it up over here. It says Simulating shipping the Nerf football to Tim, in Scranton [he mispronounces the word "in" and repeats it correctly]
4. and we're gonna have a same type of thing, we're gonna have a title... Let's just start with a title for now. OK, so we've got a title
5. and that might work, except for if we have things that aren't even or are even less equal [here he uses the word "or" to indicate that he misspoke, in this case he meant to say "are" instead of "aren't" so he goes back and corrects]
6. So, an interface, let's talk about that is... (and then we'll actually see it in action) is [here he starts to continue the sentence with "is" then realizes he wanted to say something else, says that, then continues with the "is" from before]
7. Now, a naming convention, probably **the** naming convention
8. First thing you/we need to do [either "you" or "we" could have been said, it doesn't matter much]
9. So let's look at our physical product model.
10. Otherwise, there's no point in putting it in the contract if no one can see it.